# How to set height of element based on content

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to set height of element. I need to clickable dots but there is an invisible height of the elements that I can click too. I tried to set `max-height` but then it will move first element out of his range. Here is my example

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 999;
  right: 5px;
}

nav>div {
  min-height: 10px;
  font-size: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    •
  </div>
  <div>
    •
  </div>
  <div>
    •
  </div>
  <div>
    •
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use code inspector to debug your HTML and CSS. It's clearly the padding coming from the size of the dot itself. Use SVG instead and set padding to 0;

Comment: I thinked too that's padding but no, maybe this is space of this dot and this is not changable value. I will use just empty div with height, width, background and rounded corners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a different approach:

Create the dots as `div` with a set width, height, a background-color and 50% `border-radius`( to make them circles). Use top and bottom margins to create the vertical distance:

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 999;
  right: 5px;
}

nav>div {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ye, this is the easiest way to solve this problem that I did not think about. Thanks :)